# Access to "hidden" variables in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

Some example models that are included in the Simulink library, include some variables that their value is not visible. For instance, in the model power_PVarray_grid_det the sample time of the powergui is defined as Ts_Power. I can not figure out the value of this variable. Is there a way to find these hidden variables, have access to them and change their value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does that model come from?  It doesn't appear to be a MathWorks created model that ships with the product.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Here is the link of the example https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/examples/detailed-model-of-a-100-kw-grid-connected-pv-array.html

Comment: Check the model callbacks or the model workspace.

Comment: For this model it is defined in model "PreLoadFcn" callback.